# why is the 'Dynamic Ownership Chain' mode of a stored procedure mutually exclusive to "chained" / "unchained"?

Tags: sybase, sybase-ase

How is the "chained" / "unchained" / "any" transaction mode for a stored procedure related to the "[no] dynamic ownership chain" mode?

Reading the Sybase ASE documentation on the `sp_procxmode` system stored procedure it appears that these modes are mutually exclusive in the sense that a stored procedure can only have only one of the following five execution modes:

- chained
- unchained
- any
- dynamic ownership chain
- no dynamic ownership chain

This is corroborated by the fact that `sp_procxmode` reports only one of the above five values for a given stored procedure.

… yet, according to the documentation `[no] dynamic ownership chain` is about permissions only and, thus, unrelated to chaining:

> To change a stored procedure’s transaction mode, enter:
>
> `sp_procxmode procname, tranmode`
>
> When you create a stored procedure,
>   Adaptive Server tags it with the current session’s transaction mode.
>   This means:
>
> - You can execute “chained” stored procedures only in sessions using
>     chained transaction mode.
> - You can execute “unchained” stored procedures only in sessions using
>     unchained transaction mode.
>
> To execute a particular stored procedure in either chained or
>   unchained sessions, set its transaction mode to “anymode”.
>
> If you attempt to run a stored procedure under the wrong transaction
>   mode, Adaptive Server returns a warning message, but the current
>   transaction, if any, is not affected.
>
> Executing `sp_procxmode procname, 'Dynamic Ownership Chain'` makes sure
>   that any Dynamic SQL (execute immediate) statements within the stored
>   procedure get their permissions checked against the procedure creator.
>
> Executing `sp_procxmode procname, 'No Dynamic Ownership Chain'` (the default behaviour if omitted) makes sure that any Dynamic SQL (execute immediate) statements within the stored procedure get their permissions checked against the procedure executor.

The above description leads me to believe that the "dynamic ownership chain" mode of a stored procedure is really unrelated / orthogonal to the "chained" / "unchained" status so I don't understand why they are treated as mutually exclusive.